# Task done right, answer not being accepted

Tags: c++

I am having issues with a task I've done, it outputs answer correctly without any errors. It gives me 2/3 points, last shows error, and doesn't show what. I've no clue what I've done wrong. Can someone have a look at this please.

**Task:**

```
A perfect number is a natural number that is equal to the sum of all its natural divisors (different from itself).
6 = 1 + 2 + 3
28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14

A redundant number is a natural number which is greater than the sum of all its natural divisors (different from itself).
9> 1 + 3

The deficit number is a natural number that is less than the sum of all its natural divisors (different from itself).
12 <1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6
```

Input

A natural number N (N <1000) followed by N natural numbers (not greater than 32000).
Remember 0 is an natural number.

For each of the numbers given in the input, the program should print a line of the form on the screen:

`X - perfect / redundant / deficit number`
depending on the type of number.

Sample input
`6 15 28 6 56 22 496`

Sample output

```
15 - redundant number

28 - perfect number

6 - perfect number

56 - deficit number

22 - redundant number

496 - a perfect number
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ifPerfect(int n)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n / 2; i++)
    if (n % i == 0)
      sum += i;
  if (sum == n)
  {
    cout << n << " - perfect number" << endl;
  }
}

void ifRedundant(int n)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
      sum += i;
    }
  }
  if (n > sum)
  {
    cout << n << " - redundant number" << endl;
  }
}

void ifDeficit(int n)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
      sum += i;
    }
  }

  if (n < sum)
  {
    cout << n << " - deficit number" << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  if (n >= 0 && n < 1000)
  {

    int *tab = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      cin >> tab[i];
    }

  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      ifRedundant(tab[i]);
      ifPerfect(tab[i]);
      ifDeficit(tab[i]);
    }

    delete[] tab;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the source?

Comment: What source? I've added all code I've.

Comment: I meant source of the task. Just making sure it is not from a live contest.

Comment: Oh, it's custom task from my university.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why they included the "remember" bit. What should this print for zero? Yours says perfect, I think that's not correct.

Comment: @dratenik, I don't really know, that's why I added   `if (n >= 0 && n < 1000)`

Comment: I mean zero as one of the `tab[i]` numbers.

Comment: Just a shot into blue: AFAIU, a natural number is either perfect, or redundant, or deficit. Thus, it should be possible to check this in only one function. I guess, at least one of the cases allows an early bail-out.

Comment: you do not need `tab` at all. Your code is quite repetitive. You didn't describe how you can gain points. It is possible your code is simply to slow. Your implementation is naive brutal force approach, so it is possible to make it faster and gain points.

Comment: Are you provided the input that causes the failure? If so, step through the program with the debugger that came with your development tools and keep an eye out for the unexpected. If you're still stuck, add the input to the question.

Comment: When I saw the title of this question I thought this was a MSO question!

Comment: To speed up your code, use a table of the first 25 or more prime numbers.  Allow expanding of the table as necessary.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj Michigan Symphony Orchestra?

Comment: @user4581301: No, I meant Meta Stack Overflow.  SO = Stack Overflow, MSO = Meta Stack Overflow, *.SE means that respective Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number), 0 is NOT a perfect number, while your program would say that it is.

Given an input of `0`, you program will produce an incorrect answer.

The clue was the statement "Remember 0 is an natural number."

While `natural`, it is not `perfect`.

Comment: depending on definition of natural number zero can be and input or not.

Comment: It seems a comment more than an answer. Also, it does not help anyone – consider adding more effort to your answer.

Comment: @RohanBari - I thought that it did answer a question, by pointing to an incorrect result. However, I've added explicit statement of it now.

Comment: @MarekR please note: `"Remember 0 is an natural number."`